# fllutter I18n is throwing an exception when used in nested widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I am writing a flutter app, where I am using the flutter I18n package. It works fine on the most placed, but when I try to use it in a method, which creates an other widget, it crashes with the following error.

> The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building LightLocationWidget(dirty, dependencies: [_LocalizationsScope-[GlobalKey#ced6b]], state: _LightLocationWidgetState#3b5b6):
>   The getter 'decodedMap' was called on null.
>   Receiver: null
>   Tried calling: decodedMap
>   When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
>    Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:51:5)
>    FlutterI18n._translateWithKeyFallback (package:flutter_i18n/flutter_i18n.dart:162:43)
>    FlutterI18n.translate (package:flutter_i18n/flutter_i18n.dart:139:26)

In the package its this method:

```
static String _translateWithKeyFallback(
  final BuildContext context, final String key) {
final Map<String, dynamic> decodedStrings =
    _retrieveCurrentInstance(context).decodedMap;
String translation = _decodeFromMap(decodedStrings, key);
if (translation == null) {
  print("**$key** not found");
  translation = key;
}
return translation;}
```

My code which throws the exception:

```
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Row(
          children: [
      Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: getLightButton(1),
      )

      ...

   ButtonTheme getLightButton(int typeNumber) {   
    return ButtonTheme(
      child: FlatButton(
        child: Column(children: [Text(FlutterI18n.translate(context, "lightlocation")
      ...
```

When I use this key directly on the widget it works without problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem. I was using `MaterialApp` twice. One Time in my main and also on another screen. Switching to `Scaffold` on the other screen solved the problem.